# How to add a footer line above an equation only in one specific page of a two column paper

Tags: header-footer

[image: footer]

How can I add a footer line in one page of a double column paper?
An example is added here.

Comment: @Sara Hesami IMO that is not a footer, that is instead a double column equation of a `IEEEtran` class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `figure*` environment and use a temporary counter for the equations at the bottom. The `stfloats` package is also required to use the `[!b]` option. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{stfloats,lipsum} 

\newcounter{mytempeqncnt}

\begin{document} 

\lipsum[10]

\begin{figure*}[!b]
\normalsize
\hrulefill
\vspace*{4pt}
\setcounter{mytempeqncnt}{\value{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{5}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn_dbl_x}
x = 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + 15 + 17 + 19 + 21+ 23 + 25 + 27 + 29 + 31
\end{equation}
\setcounter{equation}{\value{mytempeqncnt}}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, However, I get an error for the rest of my figures.

Comment: Then, you need to provide a MWE, a small sample of your document, with the real setup and used packages that we can copy-paste-compile and replicate the errors you mention. Without this, you have a very little chance of getting a good help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But may I just ask, when we set the temporary counter, It is fixed to a number e.g. (5) then 5 is repeated for other equations in my text. how can I forth the equation numbers to jump from 4 to 6, so 5 can be set to my equation in the footer.